# Flutter Awesome Notifications PlatformException Unknown Error

Tags: ios, flutter, notifications, simulator, awesome-notifications

I followed ResoCoder's guide on how to set up everything having to do with the **Awesome Notifications Plugin**. When I try creating a new basic notification, this error is called:

### My Code to Initialize

```
AwesomeNotifications().initialize('resource://drawable/res_notification_logo', [
NotificationChannel(
    channelKey: 'basic_channel',
    defaultColor: Colors.tealAccent,
    channelName: 'Basic '
        'Notifications',
    importance: NotificationImportance.High,
    channelShowBadge: true,
    channelDescription: 'Basic notifications for Fredi.')]);
```

### My Code To Call Notifications

```
Future<void> createBasicNotification() async {
try {
        await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
       content: NotificationContent(
                id: createUniqueId(),
                channelKey: 'basic_channel',
                title: '${Emojis.money_coin} Test Notification Title',
                body: 'This is your first notification boy',
                bigPicture: 'assets://assets/frediLogoSlogan.png',
                notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture));
      } on PlatformException catch (error) {
        print("$error");
      }
    }
```

Then I call:

```
onPressed: () async {
          print('pressed');
          await createBasicNotification();
        },
```

### The Error (Output)

`pressed`

`flutter: PlatformException(exception, Unknow error, The operation couldn’t be completed. (awesome_notifications.AwesomeNotificationsException error 1.), null)`

I don't know what to fix as there is no description.

Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found what was wrong, this line:

```
bigPicture: 'assets://assets/frediLogoSlogan.png'
```

should be:

```
bigPicture: 'asset://assets/frediLogoSlogan.png',
```

The error description was only given if I tried on the android simulator. So give that a try of no error description is given.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have initialize and asked for permission to show notification

```
    await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
  if (!isAllowed) {
    AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
  }
});
```